# Why does TextView not expand and cut the text?

Tags: java, android, xml

I put a text from a database, but in the field shows only two lines and the rest of the text is cut off and put three dots.

file.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/svRut"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="right" >

 <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/llRut"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="5dp" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDescript"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="@string/mus_textdes" />
</LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

File.java

```
...
textDescript.setText(onExes.getString(onExes.getColumnIndex("exes_desc")));
...
```

[image: Screen the problem]

Comment: You may encapsulate your `TextView` inside `ScrollView`. You dont need `LinearLayout` here.

Comment: I brought a piece of code, this `LinearLayout` still have other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does TextView not expand and cut the text?

=> Just because you have included `android:ellipsize="end"`, **remove** it if you don't want that ending dots.

Comment: but then why its showing two lines.It should show dots on single line ending.

Comment: It's amazing, but helped. But if I put a static field with a lot of text without using `android:ellipsize="end"`, then it goes off the screen. Honestly do not understand why, if you can link to an explanation of the situation. Thank you!

Comment: @Roman: android:ellipsize having 5 static values those are: none, start, middle, end and marquee.depending upon set the values it shows different outputs.check from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `android:maxLines="1"`. then it will occupy 1 line only

Comment: I meant to bring all of the text, not just the first line.